# Comparison between datetime64[ns] and date

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have DataFrame with values looks like this

```
    Date        Value 
1   2020-04-12  A
2   2020-05-12  B   
3   2020-07-12  C   
4   2020-10-12  D
5   2020-11-12  E
```

and I need to create new DataFrame only with dates from today (7.12) to future (in this example only rows 3, 4 and 5).

I use this code:

```
df1= df[df["Date"] >= date.today()]
```

but it gives me **TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date**

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Use the `.dt.date` on the `df['Date']` column. Then you are comparing dates with dates. So:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['Date'].dt.date >= date.today()]
```

This will give you:

```
        Date Value
3 2020-12-07     C
4 2020-12-10     D
5 2020-12-11     E
```

Also make sure that your dateformat is actualy correct. For example by print `df['Date'].dt.month` to see that it gives all `12`'s. If not, your date string is not converted correctly. In that case, use `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%Y-%d-%m")` to convert the Date column to the correct datetime format after creating the DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. This considers that your dates are in `YYYY-DD-MM` format, in case its other format then one could change date format accordingly in `strftime` function.

```
import pandas as pd
today=pd.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%d-%m")
df.loc[df['Date'] >= today]
```

***Sample run of solution above:*** Let's say we have following test DataFrame.

```
    Date        Value 
1   2020-04-12  A
2   2020-05-12  B   
3   2020-07-12  C   
4   2020-11-12  D
5   2020-12-12  E
```

Now when we run the solution above we will get following output:

```
      Date   Value
3   2020-07-12  C   
4   2020-11-12  D
5   2020-12-12  E
```